# Change subview controller programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I have a page-based application of 3 pages, on every page I have a `UIView` as a subview, this `UIView` is loaded from a `UIViewController`. On the last page, I have a `UICollectionView` containing different items, **when I touch on a `UICollectionCell` I would like to change the subview.**

Here is my storyboard:

[image]

The Orange `UIView` is loaded with views from `UIViewController`s (with xib files)

And the `viewWillAppear:` on `DataViewController.m`:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.dataLabel.text = [self.dataObject description];

    if([self.dataLabel.text isEqualToString:@"View1"])
        [mainView addSubview: view1.view];
    else if([self.dataLabel.text isEqualToString:@"View2"])
        [mainView addSubview: view2.view];
    else if([self.dataLabel.text isEqualToString:@"View3"]){
        [mainView addSubview: view3.view];
    }
}
```

And the method how handle touching the `UICollectionCell`:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
            didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   // Change the view
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could delegate the events on UICollectionView to DataViewController to handle these easier.

---

1- Identify your `UICollectionView` with a tag to retrieve it easily  :

```
//Supposed that your UICollectionView has been declared as an IBOutlet in your .h
yourCollectionView.tag = 1;
```

2- Add `<UICollectionViewDelegate>` to your `DataViewController.h` to handle `UICollectionView` events,

3- Set your View's `UICollectionView`  delegate on `DataViewController` just after you added it to the `mainView` :

```
//Replace 1 with the NSInteger you chose
[[[mainView subviews] lastObject] viewWithTag:1] setDelegate:self];
```

4- Handle the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` on your `DataViewController` to change your view.

Answer (score 0):

try like this it'l helps you bring subview which view you want,

```
 [self.view bringSubviewToFront:view];
```

Comment: This will load also the Controller of the view ?

Comment: Argument of bringSubviewToFront: method is not a string, it should be UIView or its subclass.